# Upsert from Ruby FuelSDK Gem

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, ruby

The documentation for the FuelSDK-Ruby gem says that you can use the Put method to do an upsert. However, this method doesn't appear to be implemented. Is there a way to do an upsert using the FuelSDK-Ruby gem?

Here's what the wiki says:

> Support for single request to Add/Update:A single request can be made which will create the object if one doesn't already or update one if it does. This works for Subscriber, DataExtension::Row, and List objects using the Put method.

Comment: I think you are right - it's not been implemented, or if it was it's no longer there. At this point, it would require the SDK to be altered, and it's currently under community support - and would require a pull request to get updated.

Comment: @KellyJAndrews So is ExactTarget completely passing maintenance and future development of the gem on to the community going forward? I think that would be unfortunate, but if that's the case, I think it needs to be handed over to someone who will at least oversee it. Currently there are numerous issues that have went unanswered for over a year. Nobody is going to take the time to make significant contributions if those contributions aren't being considered for inclusion in a timely manner.

Comment: Not entirely no, just at the moment its been somewhat set on low priority. I'm actively trying to resolve this to provide better ruby support ongoing.

Comment: @KellyJAndrews That would be fantastic. Is there currently any workaround to do an upsert from Ruby?

Comment: I'm going to try a few things - might try adding the functionality if I can manage it :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though this has been implemented - but it's on a different version than the "official" gem listed at https://rubygems.org/gems/fuelsdk

If you clone the repo for the fuelsdk here - https://github.com/ExactTarget/FuelSDK-Ruby

And then perform `gem build fuelsdk.gemspec`

Once it's built install using - `gem install fuelsdk-0.0.5.gem`

Using this gem - you should have access to the `put()` funtionality.

#### Sample Call

```
require 'fuelsdk'

@auth = {
    'client' => {
        'id' => 'CLIENT ID',
        'secret' => 'CLIENT SECRET'
    }
}

stubObj = FuelSDK::Client.new @auth,true

 sub = FuelSDK::Subscriber.new
 sub.authStub = stubObj
 sub.properties = {
    "EmailAddress" => "test2@bh.email.com",
    "SubscriberKey" => "test2@bh.email.com"
 }
sub.put

row = FuelSDK::DataExtension::Row.new
row.customer_key = "test-de";
row.authStub = stubObj
row.properties = {"ID" => "7", "text" => "sample"}
row.put
```